# How to pass all field names to when_any argument of django-lifecycle hook

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using [django-lifecycle](https://rsinger86.github.io/django-lifecycle/) to create a function in a model to be run when any input is changed. I'm doing this using the before_update hook, e.g.

```
@hook("before_update", when_any=list_of_fields, has_changed=True)
    def do_something(self):
        do something here...
```

I am trying to pass all of the field names to the when_any argument but struggling because the hook argument cannot use self to get this. For example doing:

```
@hook("before_update", when_any=[f.name for f in self._meta.get_fields()], has_changed=True)
    def do_something(self):
        do something here...
```

gives the NameError `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

Is there a way to get all of the model field names in another way from within the model class?